Zabbix trigger configuration: ITEM.VALUE/ITEM.LASTVALUE and "last"/"avg" functions
I hope I can be clear enough in detailing this situation.
Scenario Description
Zabbix collects a value every minute.

The last value collected must be between 70% greater or 70% lesser than the average of the 5 previously collected values.
If the last value is greater than or lesser then 70%, an alert must be issued

With this in mind, let's consider two different scenarios:
Scenario 1
Consider this snippet of Last 500 values:



Index
Timestamp
Value




1
2024-08-09 11:16:20
203


2
2024-08-09 11:15:20
214


3
2024-08-09 11:14:20
183


4
2024-08-09 11:13:20
213


5
2024-08-09 11:12:20
202


6
2024-08-09 11:11:20
224



If I consider the row 1 as my last value:

Last Value = 203
Average of the previous 5 Values = (214+183+213+202+224)/5 = 207.2
Variation between Last Value and Average is calculated by:

( (Last Value - (Average + 0.0001)) / (Average + 0.0001) ) * 100

So, the variation is -2.02%. And this should not raise an alert.
Scenario 2
Consider this other snippet of Last 500 values:



Index
Timestamp
Value




1
2024-08-09 11:16:20
231


2
2024-08-09 11:15:20
130


3
2024-08-09 11:14:20
110


4
2024-08-09 11:13:20
108


5
2024-08-09 11:12:20
90


6
2024-08-09 11:11:20
95



If I consider the row 1 as my last value:

Last Value = 231
Average of the previous 5 Values = (130+110+108+90+95)/5 = 106.6
Variation between Last Value and Average is calculated by:

( (Last Value - (Average + 0.0001)) / (Average + 0.0001) ) * 100

So, the variation is 116.69%. And this MUST raise an alert.
Alert Configuration
The relevant fields of the trigger configuration form are:
Operational Data
In this field, I am trying to understand how the values are read by a Zabbix trigger.
L1: {ITEM.VALUE1}, L2: {ITEM.VALUE2}, L3: {ITEM.VALUE3}, L4: {ITEM.VALUE4}, L5: {ITEM.VALUE5}

My goal is to elaborate meaningful sentences to my users with these values.
Expression
(((last(/ino01-logserver/createdByMin.FTBNotifications) - (avg(/ino01-logserver/createdByMin.FTBNotifications,#5:now-1m)+0.0001))/(avg(/ino01-logserver/createdByMin.FTBNotifications,#5:now-1m)+0.0001))*100 > {$FTB.MAX.PERCENT})

or

avg(/ino01-logserver/createdByMin.FTBNotifications,#5:now-1m) = 0 

Please note that:

Adding 0.0001 avoids DIV/0 error;
A row of 5 ZEROS must also raise an alert, that's why the logical expression has an OR.

The malformed alert
Telegram sent me this alert:

 High Event 2348341 at logserver.utl.inovaxio
〰️

✏️ No último minuto a quantidade de Webhooks FTBK variou mais que 70% (para mais ou para menos) do que a média dos últimos 5 minutos anteriores, OU a média dos últimos 5 minutos está ZERADA

 Operational data: L1: 258, L2: 258, L3: 258, L4: 258, L5: *UNKNOWN*

⏰ Started at 08:50:20 on 2024.08.03

Operational data
Either {ITEM.VALUE<1-9>} or {ITEM.LASTVALUE<1-9>} shows always the same value. What I understood is that {ITEM.VALUE<1-9>} or {ITEM.LASTVALUE<1-9>} would be defined according to the precedence in the Expression field. So, considering Scenario 2 table:



ITEM.VALUE
Expression Item




ITEM.VALUE1
last(/ino01-logserver/createdByMin.FTBNotifications)


ITEM.VALUE2
avg(/ino01-logserver/createdByMin.FTBNotifications,#5:now-1m)


ITEM.VALUE3
avg(/ino01-logserver/createdByMin.FTBNotifications,#5:now-1m)


ITEM.VALUE4
avg(/ino01-logserver/createdByMin.FTBNotifications,#5:now-1m)


ITEM.VALUE5
UNKNOWN



So in this experience, {ITEM.VALUE1} should be different than {ITEM.VALUE2}, {ITEM.VALUE3} and {ITEM.VALUE5}. I was already expecting {ITEM.VALUE5} to fail.
Question: Why all {ITEM.VALUE} are equal?
Expression
I'm receiving much more alerts than I was expecting. So, maybe I haven't correctly translated my model to the Expression syntax.
Question: Have I misused last and/or avg functions?
